# Infinite while loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
option=n
while [ "$option" != "Y" -o "$option" != "y" ]
do
echo "Enter SIDNAME"
read SIDNAME

echo "Enter TNSALIAS"
read TNSALIAS

echo "Enter FQDN of the RDS"
read RDS

echo "Cofigration details provides as"
echo "SIDNAME : " $SIDNAME
echo "TNSALIAS: " $TNSALIAS
echo "FQDN of the RDS :" $RDS

echo "Do you want continue with this information? Enter y/n"
read option
done
```

I am try to achieve that if user enter any thing except `Y` then the loop re runs but this is a infinite loop not breaking even if I enter Y.

I know I am making this some silly mistake.

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `-a`, not `-o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-a` instead of `-o` in the condition. You want to terminate when it's `Y` or `y`, i.e. it should run while it's not `Y` AND it's not `y`.

Also, in bash you can use the `[[` condition and use a pattern on the right hand side:

```
while [[ $option != [Yy] ]]
```

Comment: This works! thanks Choroba!